# No appropriate loader to handle js WebPack babel-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babel-loader

I got unexpected error about bundling a JSON data. I tried to use json-loader to bundle json, but got the same error there.

```
ERROR in ./src/index.js 6:7
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import data from './data/recipes.json';
| 
> render(<Menu recipes={data} />, document.getElementById('root'));

webpack 5.53.0 compiled with 1 error in 82 ms
```

./src/index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { render} from 'react-dom';
import Menu from './components/Menu';
import data from './data/recipes.json';

render(<Menu recipes={data} />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'assets'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }]
  }
};
```

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/preset-env", 
    [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      {
        "runtime": "automatic"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "recipes-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "serve": "^12.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "webpack": "^5.53.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0"
  }
}
```

In 'webpack.config.js' file I tried to change 'loader' to 'use', same thing...

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom' and ReactDOM.render() also same thing...

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans , as I said I tried that before, but according this book:
https://www.amazon.com/Learning-React-Modern-Patterns-Developing/dp/1492051721.  Page 164

there shouldn't be any specific loaders for json files. Seems like it used to work this way with older versions of webpack.

Comment: Looking closer at the error, Line 6, column 7 is that `<` so it looks like JSON is not your problem, JSX is. Borrow a bit of the code from https://www.robinwieruch.de/minimal-react-webpack-babel-setup and see how far that gets you?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, changed that to: rules: [{ test: /\.js?$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader' }], doesn't work either.
The same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

webpack.config.js was at the wrong place of a dir structure.